# How to correctly implement History.js or any other alternative (jquery bbq, pjax, jquery adress) in this application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, history.js, pjax, jquery-bbq

Core of the page that am working on looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/AUCYf/1/ and when user lands on it from search engine the content in 'toggle box' that has been searched shoud be opened. I found a lot of tutorials on making AJAX crawlable but am stuck at implementing scripts that i mentioned in title.
What happens now is when I click on button 'LINK1' div1 opens and url is: mypage.com/#link1
I need that div1 opened when visiting mypage.com/#link1 directly.
Also, because more div's can be opened at the same time, is there a way to do something like this mypage.com/#link1&link3

Comment: my solution to this would involve checking the `window.location` to see if the `hash` found in our `window.location` was the same as some `unique identifier populated into the container by the ajax call.` If it's not, then `create a conditional statement to perform the above described`.

Comment: thanks for answer. is there any example of it on web? am not that good in js so i cant do it straight from my head.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of achieving this using jQuery BBQ is to bind to the window hashchange event to handle ajax hash-history-based navigation, then manually trigger the hashchange event upon first load of the app.

jQuery BBQ uses parameterized hash state and can manage multiple params independently. So for example, your url could look like

```
mypage.com/#a=link1&b=link3
```

To make this work, you'd want to change the onclick events to use BBQ pushState instead of just href="#link1" on your anchors.

Putting it all together we could have something like:

```
$('.show_hide1').click(function(){
    $.bbq.pushState({'a':'link1'});
});

...

$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
    var state = $.bbq.getState();
    //do something with the state
    if(state['a'] === 'link1') {
        $(".slidingDiv1").fadeToggle();
    }
    ...
}

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

The *$(window).trigger('hashchange');* will fire when your script is loaded and automatically load the appropriate content from the URL.

Check out the jQuery BBQ docs [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#jQuery.bbq.pushState) and you may want to look at his examples for managing multiple hash-states independently.

Comment: Somehow page stops working when second part of code is inserted:  `$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
    var state = $.bbq.getState();
    //do something with the state
    if(state['a'] === 'link1') {
        $(".slidingDiv1").fadeToggle();
    }
}`  All divs are opened and nothing happens on click